# Not getting query string value using angular.js

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a URL like this `http://localhost/phpdemo/edit_data.php?edt_id=1`. Here I need the query string value which is `1`. By using Angular.js, I am getting the following output in browser's console.

```
id is : Object {}
```

My code is given below.

> update.js:

```
var app=angular.module("edit_data", []);
app.controller("updateController",function($scope,$http,$location){
    $scope.errors = [];
    $scope.msgs = [];
    var id=$location.search();
    console.log("id is :",id);
    $http.get('js/edit.php',{"user_id":$location.hash()}).success(function(response){
        console.log('response',response);
    });
    $scope.update_data=function(){
        $http.post('js/update.php',{"first_name":$scope.first_name,"last_name":$scope.last_name,"city":$scope.city}
        ).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            if(data.msg!=''){
            $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
            }else{
                $scope.errors.push(data.error);
            }
        }).error(function(data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs
               // or server returns response with an error status.
              $scope.errors.push(status);
        });
    }
});
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This `$location.search();` return an array, so

```
console.log("id is :",id[0]);
```

Can you try with above.

UPDATE:

```
$location.search()['edt_id']
```

It must return the value 1

Comment: @ Sameera : No its again showing the output `undefined`.Can you share your total angular code.

Answer (score 0):

$location.search() will return an object of key-value pairs, the same pairs as the query string. A key that has no value is just stored in the object as true. In this case, the object would be:

```
var id=$location.search().edt_id;
```

**Location service Search Little Brief**

search(search, [paramValue]);
This method is getter / setter.

Return search part (as object) of current url when called without any parameter.

Change search part when called with parameter and return $location.

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var searchObject = $location.search();
// => {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}

// set foo to 'yipee'
$location.search('foo', 'yipee');
// $location.search() => {foo: 'yipee', baz: 'xoxo'}
```

Comment: Its showing the output `cc {$$protocol: "http", $$host: "localhost", $$port: 80, $$path: "", $$search: Object…}`.

Comment: Check the edited answer. Try : $location.search().edt_id

Comment: No,its showing the output `undefined`.BTW i am using angular version 1.4.6.

Comment: Better you console.log($location.search()) and see the type of object and traverse depending on that. The solution I have shared is how ppl are doing. I am not getting how it is not working for you.